# How to make field conditionally required in Acumatica?

Tags: erp, acumatica

Let's say I have DAC class with two fields. Boolean ( let's it's name is IsDateRequired ) and DateTime ( let's name it DateReceive ). Is it possibel to make field DateReceive required only in case if IsDateRequired equal to true?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To make field mandatory conditionally, you need to use `PXDefaultAttribute.SetPersistingCheck<DAC.Field>(pxcache, data, PXPersistingCheck.<Value>)` method in `_RowSelected` event handler.

`PXPersistingCheck.Nothing` will make field non-mandatory and `PXPersistingCheck.Null/PXPersistingCheck.NullOrBlank` will make field mandatory. 
You need to make sure to have `PXDefault` attribute declared for the DAC field you are trying to make it mandatory conditionally. Without `PXDefault` attribute declared, static methods of `PXDefaultAttribute` will not have any impact.